# Как правильно писать слово раздались или роздались?

Tags: орфография

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @tkbpfdtnf22, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

В приставках "раз - роз" буква "а" пишется в безударном положении, поэтому в слове "раздались" буква "а"

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: р***а***здались.

Answer (score 0):

Вчера раздавали слонов, 
Всего была роздана сотня, 
К раздаче успел Иванов... 
Слона чел из "розыска" отнял :(

И хоть все раздались слоны,
И розданы были достойным,
Плохие раздатчики мы,
Пока розыскник* тот не пойман.

*рОзыскник - полицейский термин

Comment: В новейших рекомендациях советуют писать *разыскной, разыскник*. Решили все-таки ликвидировать исключение.  
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/302837/разыскник

Answer (score 0):

Вчера раздавали слонов, 
Всего была роздана сотня, 
К раздаче успел Иванов... 
Слона чел из "розыска" отнял :(

И хоть все раздались слоны,
И розданы были достойным,
Плохие раздатчики мы,
Пока розыскник* тот не пойман.

*рОзыскник - полицейский термин